# How do I get the "clip with another polygon layer" tool/plugin from QGIS version 2.14.1

Tags: qgis, clip

Hello I'm looking for help finding and downloading a plugin/tool from a previous version of QGIS (2.14.1). It's called the "clip with polygon from another layer" and I would like to download it for the latest version of QGIS (2.18.14). Whenever I've searched plugins on the QGIS desktop it doesn't show up and I've also looked on the QGIS plugin website online and it isn't in their either to my knowledge. If anyone has any idea of how i can get this plugin/tool on the latest version it would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you mean clip with polygon from the same layer (rather than another layer)?

Comment: Nope it's definitely from another layer, what I'm trying to do is clip excess grid lines that are outside of the polygon boundary. I tried what MappaGnosis told me to do and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it.  Simply select the polygon you want to use as your 'clipper' in one layer and then use the normal clip tool (`Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Clip`).  If all polygons in the clipper layer are unselected, then all are used.  If one or more polygons are selected in the clipper layer, then the selected ones are used.

If you meant clip with a polygon from the same layer - try the plugin called [Clipper](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clipper/)

Comment: Ok so I have a vector grid that is overlaying a polygon. all I'm trying to do is use the polygon as a border to get rid of excess grid lines that lie outside of the polygon that the grid is overlaying.

Comment: When you say above 'it didn't work' can you be more specific.  This should be a simple operation so without any further information it is impossible to say what you did wrong.  One thing that does spring to mind is are both layers in the same CRS?  Even when re-projecting on the fly you can get some unexpected results.